# memcache for php - unable to connect

Tags: php, linux, apache, nginx

I m running centos 6. Using apache for handling php and nginx to handle scripts images and css

i have installed memcached server.

```
PORT="11211"
USER="memcached"
MAXCONN="4096"
CACHESIZE="512"
OPTIONS="-l 127.0.0.1"
```

i have also installed the module for php.

i created a new php file

```
 $memcache = new Memcache;
 $memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

i checked the memcached status and it is running.
I am always getting "Could not connect".
I tried to change the value to 'localhost' from '127.0.0.1' - still not working.

```
$memcache = new Memcache();
$memcache->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
var_dump($memcache->getExtendedStats());
$memcache->set('key', 'hello world', false, 60);
echo $memcache->get('key');
//$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

Output

```
array(1) { ["127.0.0.1:11211"]=> bool(false) }
```

What does connect and addServer do differently? Which is best way to do?
But i am not getting the Hello World

More updates on the code and on this problem..

**phpinfo** is showing memcached.
var_dump($memcache->get('key')); gives

```
bool(false)
```

why should i use **addServer** instead of **connect**?

More update on the code

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->addServer('localhost', 11211);
echo $memcache->getServerStatus('localhost', 11211);
output : 1

//$memcache->set('key', 'hello world') or die("failed to store data");
output : failed to store data
```

few more details

```
getsebool httpd_can_network_memcache
```

it returns **off**

Should it return on?

```
Notice: Memcache::connect(): Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: Permission denied (13)
```

Comment: have you tried "telnet 127.0.0.1 11211"

Comment: yes, i did. i got connected. Escape character is ...

Comment: Is memcache daemon running on same server you are attempting to execute the code on?

Comment: yes. on the same server.

Comment: If you are running SELinux or IPTables, try disabling both and see if you still have connection issues.

Comment: in case, if they are blocking, where can i check the error or warning? Can you share command to test it without disabling them?

Comment: telnet host_name 11211 -> connecting?

Comment: telnet host_name|localhost|127.0.0.1|server_ip_address 11211 => everything is connecting when i try telnet on the server

Comment: `ps -Af | grep memcached` what is the output

Comment: If for some reason SELinux is blocking php from communicating with memcache, you could look at the `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. To check if SELinux is enabled do `cat /selinux/enforce`, if it responds with one it's enabled. Another idea, try restarting both memcache and apache services...

Comment: selinux is running. i am sure. it seems it is blocking the memcached. what is the best way to run it?

Comment: @MikePurcell It is selinus. is memcached a stable one to use on busy sites? i stopped memcached and checked connected with php and it returned bool(true). why that so?

Comment: @MikePurcell post it as an answer, I will accept it. Additionally if you have any information about memcached please share it. like optimization, security..

Comment: Notice: MemcachePool::getstats(): Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: Network timeout (0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As flushed out in the comments, it appears you are running Security-Enhanced Linux (SELinux) which adds an extra layer of security at the kernel level. In my experience and usage, I found that SELinux adds a force field around certain services so that they cannot access particular assets on the system. For example, if I want to serve html content from `/home/src/web`, I have to tell the system that it is ok for the httpd service to access content in the `/home/src/web` path. To do this I would issue the following command:

```
$ -> setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1
```

Basically, to allow cross-communication between services, you have to allow such access via a policy, much like "pinholing" a firewall to allow access to a specific port, except with SELinux you are not granting access to a port, rather you are granting access to another part of the system, or service. Fortunately for us, there are several built in policies which we can use the above `setsebool` construct, rather than trying to define our own policies, which can be a pain. For a more complete explanation of SELinux check out the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELinux).

Now to answer your specific questions:

**why should i use addServer instead of connect?**

`addserver()` will allow you to add multiple ips (or hostnames) to a list from which it is assumed that cached values are present, i.e. a pool of memcache servers. Whereas the `connect()` will only allow you to connect to the single, specified server.

**getsebool httpd_can_network_memcache, it returns off, Should it return on?**

Yes, it appears that turning on this specific setting will allow you to connect to a memcache server, with SELinux enabled, however on my production servers I still have it set to off, but have the following set:

```
$ -> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

I believe, that either setting will accomplish the objective, however with the above setting, if you have a memcache server on another host, httpd can still access it.

Here is a decent [write-up](http://tag1consulting.com/blog/stop-disabling-selinux) on pinholing SELinux to allow httpd service access to other services.

Comment: Mike Purcell give return getsebool httpd_can_network_memcache on my system. can you please help me