# SOAP WebService PHP can't access extensions functions

Tags: php, oracle, web-services, soap, memcached

I'm coding a SOAP WebService in PHP and I encounter an issue.

This service is running on a Linux server. I have a function to connect to an Oracle database and another one to connect to a local Memcached server.

So, when I call my Oracle connections's function, SOAP returns :

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Call to undefined function oci_connect()

But if I create a simple php file with the same Oracle function it's work fine (without SOAP)

I created a simple server/client php files juste for testing and I encounter the same issue, here's my code :

Server :

```
<?php
class Serveur{

    function helloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    function connexionOracle()
    {
        $conn = oci_connect('XXXXX', 'XXXX', 'XXXXX');
        if($conn == false)
        {
            return "Error";
        }
        else
        {
            return "OK";
        }
    }
}
$serversoap = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => "http://localhost/test/"));
$serversoap->setClass("Serveur");
$serversoap->handle();
?>
```

Client :

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    $client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "http://localhost/test/serveur.php",'uri'=> "http://localhost/test/"));

    print_r($client->helloWorld());
    echo "</br>";
    print_r($client->connexionOracle());
 ?>
```

This code returns :

> Call to undefined function oci_connect()

But if I use a simple file like this one, everything is working :

```
$conn = connexionOracle2();
var_dump($conn);

function connexionOracle2()
{
    $db = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = XXXXX)(Port = XXXX)) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = XXXXXX) ) )";
    return oci_connect('cartetest', 'evol', $db) or Die('Connexion Oracle impossible');
}
```

I don't encounter this issue on my local windows machine

Comment: What is the server you are working with ??

Comment: I'm working with Apache and PHP 5.4

Comment: Are you able to generate the WSDL for your service ?? Are you calling the correct service name its binded port ?

Comment: For my little example i was in no wsdl mode but in my real service i can generate the WSDL file. I can also call some basic functions but if i have a function who has to connect to Oracle or Memcached i have an error like "Call to undefined function oci_connect()".

But if i try to call oci_connect from a simple php file (without the soap layer) it's working.

Comment: This solution works for me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420113/memcache-for-php-unable-to-connect/18432472#18432472

Comment: I am glad you have found a solution. :) Can I suggest you to put the solution in the post section coz it will be great help for future solution seekers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me :

> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

You can also disabled SELinux like this in the configuration file :

> SELINUX=disabled