# PHP cant connect to memcached server

Tags: php, memcached, centos7

## Background

I am running memcache for some global variables on my website. I have installed it dozens of times on centOS 6 servers with no problems. However one of our servers recently got corrupted and was rebuilt as centOS 7. I decided to take this oportunity to learn the new OS so I can eventually migrate all my servers over. However php can not seem to connect to the memcached server on localhost.

## Versions

CentOS 7.2
Apache 2.4.6
PHP 5.5.38
php-memcache 3.0.8
Memcached 1.4.15

## Removing the obvious answers

Memcached service is running on the default port as confirmed by a simple telnet ping:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
version
VERSION 1.4.15
quit
Connection closed by foreign host.
$
```

Phpinfo() confirms memcache is installed and visible to php. Also the actual commands are found.

[image: php info]

The server is on a firewalled sub-network so their is no firewall running on it and even if their was it should not affect localhost communications.

## The problem

I check memcache status with a simple php script found on [github](https://github.com/lagged/memcache.php/blob/master/memcache.php).
It returns: **"Cant connect to:127.0.0.1:11211"**. This script works on all my other servers with the similar configurations.

Using connect directly get me the assert error:

**"Memcache::connect(): Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: Permission denied (13)"**

## The question.

I verified the server is running on the desired port via telnet and the memcache library is installed and running over php. What am I missing? Is their a problem with the server/php versions or something about CentOS 7 that requires an extra step for servers to communicate to eachother? I know I had to do some selinux setting to change the ssh default port is that related?

Thanks in advance for just reading my novel of a question.

Comment: This appears to be answered by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420113/memcache-for-php-unable-to-connect. It was a salinux issue solved with the command: `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1` I marked as duplicate as someone else may have the same issue with different key words like I did.